# Create config file in PHP example

Tags: php

I need advice for this step. I create config file for my website and i write some line of codes. Need advice am i write correctly and if i need to change something.

**config.php -> file**

```
define('BASE_DIR', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', BASE_DIR,'/template/');
.
.
.
define('DIR_IMAGES', BASE_DIR,'/template/images/');
.
.
```

etc... And when i display this into example home page...

```
<?php include('config/config-file.php'); ?>
.
.
.
<img src="<?php echo DIR_IMAGES(); ?>/logo.png" alt="" />
```

I write this for first time and need good advices for this one. Thanks all for help if you need more information say.

Answer (score 0):

The `define()` function takes two arguments, so you should only have one comma. Where you have the second, you want to use a `.` instead, for string concatenation:

```
define('DIR_IMAGES', BASE_DIR . '/template/images/');
```

Also, `DIR_IMAGES` is a constant, not a function. So don't do this:

```
<img src="<?php echo DIR_IMAGES(); ?>/logo.png" alt="" />
```

Do this:

```
<img src="<?php echo DIR_IMAGES; ?>/logo.png" alt="" />
```

You can also use the shortcut style:

```
<img src="<?= DIR_IMAGES ?>/logo.png" alt="" />
```

Comment: Okay, do you think is that good line of code for config file and do that for all type of directory or base url etc?

Comment: It's certainly a better choice than hard-coding the directory name everywhere you're using it. I'd change the `include()` to a `require_once()` though -- because you want the script to fail if the config file is not present.

Comment: Thanks for advice.